# Generate PDF from a local data source -with an RDLC- in an SSIS task

Tags: ssis, rdlc

I need to generate a PDF using a local data source (e.g. C# `List<>`) using a local (**RDLC**) report - from within an **SSIS** task. I do not want to reference an SSRS url. I need the report data generation to be in a separate step from the report rendering. I have done similar things in ASP.NET by passing a `List<>` as the report data source, and then generating the PDF without displaying the report.

However, I cannot find a way to do this in SSIS. All the examples I have seen just generate an online SSRS report. Has anyone else done something like this in an SSIS task?

Comment: I still think you want to use a URL to call the report and render as a PDF.

What are you attempting to use the list for? Parameters or a data set?

Comment: The list is a data set to populate the report data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, I can load my own dlls in an SSIS script task by following the method (more or less) used in this link. https://richardswinbank.net/ssis/loading_external_assemblies

This has worked for me in the past for other purposes. However, in this case I was trying to generate a PDF by using the Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll ver=15.0.0.0. Unfortunately, one of its dependencies (Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll) would not work using this method. No matter what I tried, I would get an error message something like the below when executing the Render() method.

*ReportProcessingException: Failed to load expression host assembly. Details: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.*

I googled, binged, ChatGPtd other ways of doing this but nothing worked. One suggestion (from bing) was using a **Report Task** in SSIS which evidently comes from the Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServicesReportTask.dll. I could not find that Task, or that dll, anywhere.

Another possibility which could have worked was using the 3rd party ZappySys Report Generator Task, which evidently has support for doing this. I did not do that because of the cost.

In the end, I went back to what Microsoft recommends, but what I had not had to do up to this point - putting the dlls into the GAC. I ended up having to put 2 dlls into the GAC.

1. Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll
2. Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll

The Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll was successfully loaded using my first method.

This worked. I can now use an SSIS task to generate a PDF from an RDLC and an object data source. This allows me to use the data for multiple purposes - not just to populate the report.